# Windows 10 home can it be remotely administrated

Tags: windows-10

I am wondering if windows 10 home supports stuff like pushing software onto the pc remotely, pushing group policies, remote desktop

Comment: Not this *pushing group policies,*. But otherwise yes.

Comment: You have access to the same settings as Group Policies via registry editing, but you don't get Group Policy Editor. I've added a few duplicates.

Comment: Windows Home also can't join a domain as far as I know, which makes pushing other things more difficult.